# How can I read multiple columns from an Access database?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have been assigned the task to calculate some values from Access and store them to Excel. My code works if I use a single-column database.

My code looks like this:

```
With Recordset
        Source = "SELECT tbl_cog.[Latitude] FROM tbl_cog WHERE Company='Bandung Food Truck Festival Members'"
        .Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection
        For Col = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
            TextBox1.Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Value
        Next
    End With
```

But when I want to read multiple columns, my code just reads one column. My code looks like this:

```
With Recordset
        Source = "SELECT tbl_cog.[Latitude], tbl_cog.[Longitude] FROM tbl_cog WHERE Company='Bandung Food Truck Festival Members'"
        .Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection
        For Col = 0 To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1
            TextBox1.Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Value
            TextBox2.Value = Recordset.Fields(Col).Value
        Next
    End With
```

UPDATE:

My program with 1 column like this: https://prntscr.com/a90g5z

My program with 2 column like this: https://prntscr.com/a90gpi

My database access like this: https://prntscr.com/a90h0q

Comment: Your loop doesn't seem to be oriented in the right direction. Is there more than a single record returned? If not then why not `SELECT TOP 1 ...` to make sure? If you want to loop through the fields and not the records then the index of TextBox should be changing. The way you have it it is just putting field1 into both text boxes then putting field2 into both checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that there is only one record in `Recordset`, then you should correct your code like shown in the following snippet:

```
TextBox1.Value = Recordset.Fields(0).Value
TextBox2.Value = Recordset.Fields(1).Value
```

and so on (in case you have more than two fields). Apparently, you do not need `For` loop to complete this task.

Answer (score 1):

I have used this method to bring data from Access to Excel:

```
DataArray = Recordset.GetRows()  'all the data from the Select is transferred to an array
nb_rows = UBound(DataArray, 1)  'calculate the number of rows of the array
nb_cols = UBound(DataArray, 2)  'calculate the number of columns of the array

'paste the array to excel
Sheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(nb_rows, nb_cols)).Value = DataArray
```

'if you want the first 3 columns just replace  Cells(nb_rows, nb_cols) with Cells(nb_rows, 3)

Use this code to replace "for col=0  To Recordset.Fields.Count - 1 .... next"